# Making popup appear on mouseover and not click in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, popup, format

I'm new vwith Leaflet, and I just got started this past week. I was wondering how to make my popups fire on `mouseover` rather than the default on click.

```
  //create variable to hold the map element, give initial settings to map
  var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [38.1, -98],
    zoom: 5,
  });

  //create basemap layer
  var osm = L.tileLayer(
    "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
    {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
      subdomains: "abcd",
      maxZoom: 19,
    }
  );

  //add to map
  osm.addTo(map);

  var logo = L.icon({
    iconUrl:
      "https://d2q79iu7y748jz.cloudfront.net/s/_squarelogo/8ec294c2f144d43bf5d7ec5f4f96d0c9",
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    iconAnchor: [10, 20],
    popupAnchor: [0, -20],
  });

  // COLORADO
  L.marker([40.308746567390294, -105.08229135535235], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Berthoud, CO</h3>");

  L.marker([39.74102996214569, -104.97940776843281], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Denver, CO</h3>");
  //FLORIDA
  L.marker([30.138432902431312, -81.47832258872786], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Jacksonville, FL</h3>");
  //ILLINOIS
  L.marker([41.879448988274895, -87.6315117046291], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Chicago, IL</h3>");

  L.marker([41.8007476149432, -88.07480791524236], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Lisle, IL</h3>");

  L.marker([39.77999819036976, -89.64469580209537], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Springfield, IL</h3>");
  //KENTUCKY
  L.marker([38.04604579443191, -84.50244254581874], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Lexington, KY</h3>");
  //INDIANA
  L.marker([41.472330129058626, -87.06337336083872], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Valparaiso, IN</h3>");

  L.marker([39.77172821881897, -86.15817364592962], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Indianapolis, IN</h3>");
  //IOWA
  L.marker([41.26104429429596, -95.8669285068911], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Council Bluffs, IA</h3>");
  //MASSACHUSETTS
  L.marker([42.36045708792693, -71.05470762310003], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Boston, MA</h3>");
  //OHIO
  L.marker([39.96068992182012, -82.99568108206131], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Columbus, OH</h3>");

  L.marker([41.499389586400504, -81.68319302542062], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Cleveland, OH</h3>");
  //SOUTH CAROLINA
  L.marker([33.999310722137295, -81.04237043257584], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Columbia, SC</h3>");
  //WISCONSIN
  L.marker([44.51263315662531, -88.01247710457417], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Green Bay, WI</h3>");

  L.marker([43.060874543136336, -88.1066145780849], {
    icon: logo,
    title: "Click to find out more!",
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<h3>Brookfield, WI</h3>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called tooltip, which is displayed upon mouse enter and hidden upon mouse leave. Just use `.bindTooltip` method instead of `.bindPopup`.

If you want tooltip to appear at the same place as popup (above marker):

- use `tooltipAnchor: [0, -20]` option when defining marker icon,
- use tooltip option `{direction: 'top'}` when defining tooltip.

Simplified code could then look something like this:

```
var data = [
  {coord: [40.308746567390294, -105.08229135535235], desc: 'Berthoud, CO'},
  {coord: [39.74102996214569, -104.97940776843281], desc: 'Denver, CO'},
  .
  .
  .
];

var logo = L.icon({
  iconUrl:
    "https://d2q79iu7y748jz.cloudfront.net/s/_squarelogo/8ec294c2f144d43bf5d7ec5f4f96d0c9",
  iconSize: [20, 20],
  iconAnchor: [10, 20],
  tooltipAnchor: [0, -20]
});
  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  L.marker(data[i].coord, {
    icon: logo
  })
    .addTo(map)
    .bindTooltip('<h3>' + data[i].desc + '</h3>', {direction: 'top'});
}
```